# Why does hibernate stop working after some time?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, hibernate-cascade

I do have a system running on Apache tomcat 7 (7.0.34 if that makes any difference) with a mapping with a property like this

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "device_document",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "device_id", referencedColumnName = "device_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "document_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
public Set<Document> getDocuments() {
    return documents;
}
```

When I do call to my save function it works nice, but after some time the exact same code, with the exact same data throws an exception

```
unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

And it keeps throwing that exception everytime I try to save the instance until (sometimes) I restart the tomcat service.

Do you have any idea about why is this happening?

Comment: the usual posts about "unsaved transient instance error" reads this is about cascading, but already tried to set CascadeType to all and it is the same

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using to save? `saveOrUpdate`?

Does it throw "unsaved transient instance" only when you add `Documents` to an already save parent entity?

Try to add `CascadeType.UPDATE` to your `OneToMany` annotation.

Comment: I'm using saveOrUpate, and it happens on both cases, when adding a new parent with documents added, or updating some parent already saved, i'm gonna try the CascadeType to Update to check if that works, but today i found that my makePersistent makes flush after doing saveOrUpdate, so, i will put flush before that